# number of ways to select a committee of at least 3 students

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose a class have 7 girls and 5 boys. How many ways can a committee of at least three students of among 7 girls and 5 boys can be choosen?

and how many ways can a committee of at least 1 boy and at least 1 girl can be choosen?

Comment: Have you attempted the problem yourself already?

Comment: yes, the answer looked to long. i did what Paolo Leonetti did.

Comment: What about the new question you just edited in? Did you attempt that one?

Comment: yes, i dont know how to approach to "at least" questions. i cant count each one is to long

Comment: Now i answered both of them ;)

Answer (score 4):

Really, no costraints? Then
$$
\sum_{i=3}^{12}\binom{12}{i}=2^{12}-\binom{12}{0}-\binom{12}{1}-\binom{12}{2}=4096-79=4017.
$$

Ps. With respect to the edit, you are just saying that configurations with all the same sex is forbidden. Hence the answer is:
$$
4017-\left(2^7-\binom{7}{0}-\binom{7}{1}-\binom{7}{2}\right)-\left(2^5-\binom{5}{0}-\binom{5}{1}-\binom{5}{2}\right).
$$

Comment: tenx, but the second  question not connected to the first. meaning the committee can be with 4 people or 5......

Comment: indeed, all these combinations are counted :)